# Populate listbox with two fields MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I successfully connect to the database, get the results, but I want to use fields: name & Lastname in one option in Listbox.

I tried using + and & in between, but I only get the first field in the Listbox

```
<select>
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <option value="<?= $user['name' ]; ?>"><?= $user['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

My MYSQL fields are name & Lastname and I should get all of the options like so: 
(name Lastname)

Comment: Realized this could be done in a different way, so I used `concat` to the group name and last name directly in MySQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select>
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <option value="<?= $user['name' ] . ' ' . $user['Lastname']; ?>"><?= $user['name'] . ' ' . $user['Lastname']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

The concatenation character in PHP is a single `.`

Comment: Thank you for the short answer Matt :)

Comment: Also the option values should contain id of the rows and not name and last name